# Data overwrites from fetched URL's JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've built my own rest API (http://localhost:8080/weatherapi/{city}) this fetches simple data from an other API. If I call the data separate it works but if I loop through it it overwrites with the last fetched data.

How do I get individual data from every link?

```
let arrayOfUrls = ["http://localhost:8080/weatherapi/mechelen","http://localhost:8080/weatherapi/denbosch","http://localhost:8080/weatherapi/antwerp"];

for (let word of arrayOfUrls){
  console.log(word)
  let {data: weather} = useFetch(word);
  console.log(weather)
}
```

Comment: Google `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the response from the API request. Either use promises or a provider to wait for the response for each API. Is this using react?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).